# how to delete entire row from my database table , based on a variable using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to delete entire row from my database table , when my variable 'row_id' is 0,1,2,3,etc.... ex: when row_id is 1, then my script should delete row with the values:"1" "2017-11-06" "D" "D" "Good", when is 2 delete row with the values:"2" "2017-11-06" "SS" "SS" "Sent to repair"

My database table "cards" looks like this:

```
ID,   date,            card,      serial_card,  statuscard
"1"   "2017-11-06"     "D"        "D"           "Good"
"2"   "2017-11-06"     "SS"       "SS"          "Sent to repair"
```

I Tried:

```
 def delete(self):
     # Delete from Listbox
     selection = lb.curselection()
     lb.delete(selection[0])
     row_id=int(selection[0])
     print(row_id)
     c.execute("DELETE FROM  cards WHERE ID = ?",(row_id,))
```

My whole source code:

```
 from tkinter import *
 import sqlite3
 import time
 import datetime

 conn = sqlite3.connect('cards.db')
 c = conn.cursor()

 class MainWindow():
      def __init__(self,master):

           self.master=master
           self.master.geometry("220x120")
           self.master.title('Cards!')
           self.button2=Button(self.master,text="Status ASRU Cards",fg='blue',command=self.gotoasru)
           self.button2.place(x=50, y=20)
           self.button4=Button(self.master,text="Exit",fg='red',command=self.exit)
           self.button4.place(x=90, y=60)

      def exit(self):
           self.master.destroy()

      def gotoasru(self):
           root2=Toplevel(self.master)
           myGUI2=status_asru(root2)

 class status_asru():
     def __init__(self,master):
         self.master=master
         self.master.geometry("760x310")
         self.master.title('ASRU cards')
         self.connection = sqlite3.connect('cards.db')
         self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
         self.insert()
         self.button5=Button(self.master,text="Exit",fg='red',command= self.exit)
         self.button5.place(x=340,y=270)
     def exit(self):
         self.master.destroy()

     def insert(self):
         self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cards(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, date TEXT,card TEXT,serial_card TEXT,statuscard TEXT)')
         global insert_data
         global exit1
         global lb
         global readfromdatabase

         tipcard=StringVar()
         serial_card=StringVar()
         statuscard=StringVar()
         label1=Label(self.master,text='Insert card type:',fg='black')
         label1.place(x=5,y=120)
         label2=Label(self.master,text='Insert card SN:',fg='black')
         label2.place(x=5,y=140)
         label3=Label(self.master,text='Insert card status:',fg='black')
         label3.place(x=5,y=160)
         label4=Label(self.master,text='Select a card to be deleted from the top list',fg='black')
         label4.place(x=440,y=160)
         a=Entry(self.master,textvariable=tipcard)
         a.place(x=100,y=120)
         b=Entry(self.master,textvariable=serial_card)
         b.place(x=100,y=140)

         var1 = IntVar()
         CB1=Checkbutton(self.master, text="Good", variable=var1)
         CB1.place(x=100,y=160)
         var2 = IntVar()
         CB2=Checkbutton(self.master, text="Defect", variable=var2)
         CB2.place(x=160,y=160)
         var3 = IntVar()
         CB3=Checkbutton(self.master, text="Sent to repair", variable=var3)
         CB3.place(x=230,y=160)

         def insert_data():
             timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
             card=tipcard.get()
             SN=serial_card.get()
             if var1.get() == 1 and var2.get() == 0 and var3.get() == 0:
                status='Good'
                c.execute("INSERT INTO cards (date, card, serial_card, statuscard) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",(timestamp, card, SN, status))
                conn.commit()
             elif var1.get() ==0  and var2.get() == 1 and var3.get() == 0:
                status='Defect'
                c.execute("INSERT INTO cards (date, card, serial_card, statuscard) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",(timestamp, card, SN, status))
                conn.commit()
             elif var1.get() ==0  and var2.get() == 0 and var3.get() == 1:
                status='Sent to repair'
                c.execute("INSERT INTO cards (date, card, serial_card, statuscard) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",(timestamp, card, SN, status))
                conn.commit()
             elif var1.get() == 1 and var2.get() == 1 and var3.get() == 1:
                label5=Label(self.master,text='select only 1 status',fg='red')
                label5.place(x=105,y=180)
                var1.set(0)
                var2.set(0)
                var3.set(0)
             elif var1.get() == 0 and var2.get() == 0 and var3.get() == 0:
                label6=Label(self.master,text='select 1 status',fg='red')
                label6.place(x=105,y=180)
                var1.set(0)
                var2.set(0)
                var3.set(0)
             elif var1.get() == 1 and var2.get() == 1 and var3.get() == 0:

                label7=Label(self.master,text='select only 1 status',fg='red')
                label7.place(x=105,y=180)
                var1.set(0)
                var2.set(0)
                var3.set(0)
             elif var1.get() == 0 and var2.get() == 1 and var3.get() == 1:
                label8=Label(self.master,text='select only 1 status',fg='red')
                label8.place(x=105,y=180)
                var1.set(0)
                var2.set(0)
                var3.set(0)
             elif var1.get() == 1 and var2.get() == 0 and var3.get() == 1:                       
                label9=Label(self.master,text='select only 1 status',fg='red')
                label9.place(x=105,y=180)
                var1.set(0)
                var2.set(0)
                var3.set(0)

         lb = Listbox(self.master, width=120, height=6)
         scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.master, orient="vertical",command=lb.yview)
         scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
         lb.place(x=5,y=5)
         def readfromdatabase():
                self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cards")
                return self.cur.fetchall()
         data = readfromdatabase()
         for index, dat in enumerate(data):     
              lb.insert("end",'Card Type: '+dat[2]+3*' '+'SN: '+dat[3]+3*' '+'Status: '+dat[4]+3*' '+'Last modification date: '+dat[1] )
              self.delete=Button(self.master,text="Delete Card",fg='blue',command = lambda: delete(lb))
              self.delete.place(x=520, y=190)

              def delete(self):
                # Delete from Listbox
                selection = lb.curselection()
                lb.delete(selection[0])
                row_id=selection[0]
                print(row_id)
                c.execute("DELETE FROM  cards WHERE ID = {}".format(row_id))
                conn.commit()

         self.button4=Button(self.master,text="Insert new card",fg='green',command=insert_data)
         self.button4.place(x=100,y=200)




 def main():
      root=Tk()
      GUI=MainWindow(root)
      root.mainloop()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't stated what the problem is, however, I'm guessing that you are finding that sometimes the wrong row is being deleted from the database, or no row is being deleted?

This is because the value returned by `curselection()` is a tuple of integers corresponding to the zero-based position within the list box of the currently selected item(s). For your example, the item with ID "1" is at position 0 in the listbox. If you select that item `curselection()` will return to you the value 0, not the 1 that you require to remove the row with ID "1" from your database.

Similarly, if you had 3 items in the listbox with positions 0, 1, and 2, and you deleted the item in position 1, the last item would now be bumped up to position 1 to fill in the gap, and the listbox position and row ID will no longer be synchronised.

You can not rely on the database row ID and listbox position matching, and so you can't reliably delete rows from your table using only the listbox position. You will need to access the actual string stored in the selected item using

```
lb.get(lb.curselection())
```

and then extracting the row ID from the string (you don't show the strings stored in the listbox, so I can't advise exactly how to do that).

Alternatively, you can maintain a second data structure to map listbox position to row ID, a dictionary or list would work well. Here is a rough example:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

lb = Listbox(master)
lb.pack()

def callback():
    if not lb.curselection():
        return

    selection = int(lb.curselection()[0])
    row_id = lb.row_ids[selection]

    c.execute("DELETE FROM cards WHERE ID = ?", (row_id,))

    lb.delete(selection)
    del lb.row_ids[selection]

Button(master, text="Delete", command=callback).pack()

lb.row_ids = [1, 2, 3, 44, 12, 20]
for item in lb.row_ids:
    lb.insert(END, item)

mainloop()
```

This code uses a list containing the `row_ids`, and binds that list to the listbox object for convenience. Indexing of Python lists is also zero-based so when a listbox item is deleted, the corresponding item is deleted from the `row_ids` list.

Comment: Yeah, but is any option to auto-increment from 0 my id column ?

Comment: Something like this?  "self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cards(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT==0, date TEXT,card TEXT,serial_card TEXT,statuscard TEXT)')"

Comment: @kabanus I'm allowed to post the whole source code , for better understanding of what i want to achieve

Comment: @Razvan: auto increment will not help you. The problem is that the listbox position and the database row id will not remain synchronised when items are removed from the listbox because the position of those items following the removed one will be changed. Perhaps you could update your question to show what strings you are adding to your listbox.

Comment: Yeah i know about the problem between list and database, i'm trying to figure out best solution for this. I'll edit my post with the whole source code

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a solution that auto increment(starting with 0) my ID column from my database table, every time when i insert/delete new rows